# Unzip files and/or streams in rhomobile

Tags: mobile, zip, gzip, rhomobile, rhodes

How do I decompress a compressed file in a rhomobile application?
I saw that the zlib extension is unavailable in rhodes, because it needs a ruby port. Ruby uses the "zlib.c" or "zlib.h" source files and not a portable zlib.

When running the rhodes application, in a line with the source:

```
require 'zlib'
```

it raises the error:

```
no such file to load -- zlib
```

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on adding libaries to your Rhodes app: http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/RhodesExtensions#Adding_Libraries_to_Your_Rhodes_Application

I don't know if zlib will work or not (actually would be curious what you find out). If you have more questions I suggest the Rhomobile google group.